# Creating a .deb package for PHP 7.1

Tags: debian, packaging

I want to create a .deb package of PHP 7.1 for Debian with the PHP modules I want.

Here the steps I have followed.

1. Downloading PHP sources

   ```
   wget http://fr2.php.net/get/php-7.1.7.tar.bz2/from/this/mirror
   tar xvf mirror
   mv mirror php_7.1.7.orig.tar.bz2
   cd php-7.1.7/
   ```

Here I can compile PHP 7.1, no problem. If I want to build the package, I follow those steps:

2. Preparing the packaging:

   ```
   export DEBFULLNAME="Shanx Shanxou"
   dh_make -e shanx@example.com
   apt-get install debhelper cdbs lintian build-essential fakeroot devscripts pbuilder dh-make debootstrap

   vim debian/control
   ```

In that file I modify the `Build-Depends:` line with:

```
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), autotools-dev, mawk, file, libxml2-dev:amd64, libxml2:amd64, bison, perl-modules, libfakeroot:amd64, perl, mime-support, libmagic1:amd64    , autoconf, build-essential, git-core, libbz2-dev, libcurl4-openssl-dev, libfreetype6-dev, libicu-dev, libjpeg-dev, libmcrypt-dev, libpng-dev, libpspell-dev, libreadline    -dev, libssl-dev, libxml2-dev, pkg-config, libc-client-dev, libkrb5-dev, libpq-dev, libxslt-dev
```

3. The packaging:

   ```
   debuild -S -sa --lintian-opts -i
   cd ..
   pbuilder create
   pbuilder update --extrapackages "libc-client-dev pkg-config libssl-dev libreadline-dev libpspell-dev libpng-dev libmcrypt-dev libjpeg-dev libfreetype6-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libbz2-dev git-core mime-support libfakeroot bison libkrb5-dev libxml2-dev  debhelper"
   pbuilder build *.dsc
   ```
4. The result:

   ```
   mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/extensions': Permission denied
   mkdir: cannot create directory '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303': No such file or directory
   Makefile:160: recipe for target 'install-modules' failed
   make[1]: *** [install-modules] Error 1
   make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/buildd/php-7.1.7'
   dh_auto_install: make -j1 install DESTDIR=/tmp/buildd/php-7.1.7/debian/php AM_UPDATE_INFO_DIR=no returned exit code 2
   debian/rules:22: recipe for target 'binary' failed
   make: *** [binary] Error 2
   dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
   E: Failed autobuilding of package
   I: unmounting dev/pts filesystem
   I: unmounting run/shm filesystem
   I: unmounting proc filesystem
   I: cleaning the build env
   I: removing directory /var/cache/pbuilder/build//14827 and its subdirectories
   ```

But the directory and the file have been created by the packaging process:

```
# ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/extensions
no-debug-non-zts-20160303
```

5. The questions

Is my packaging process valid?

If so, what could be the causes of the error?

EDIT: @Stephen Kitt answer did the trick. Just to not, you have to use actual tabulations (not space) and not forget to reexecute `debuild -S -sa --lintian-opts -i` after the modification.

EDITbis : New question here [Installing a created .deb package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383404/installing-a-created-deb-package)

Comment: What does `dpkg -L php` output on the other VM? (Also, note that common practice here when someone answers your question in a useful way, is to accept the answer, not edit your question to ask another question.)

Comment: Sorry, I was not sure if it was the same question or not. I've created a new question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383404/installing-a-created-deb-package

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would have used the existing [Debian PHP 7.1 package](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/php7.1) instead...

Anyway, to answer your question, your packaging process as described is valid. To answer properly we’d need to see your `debian/control` and `debian/rules` files in detail, but the error you’re seeing is easy to fix: the PHP source doesn’t use `DESTDIR`, it needs an `INSTALL_ROOT` variable instead. In `debian/rules`:

```
override_dh_auto_install:
        dh_auto_install -- INSTALL_ROOT=$(CURDIR)/debian/php
```

since you appear to be building a single `php` binary package.

Comment: The same error is still there. Do you have any other hint?

Comment: Could you [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/383360/edit) your question to include the contents of `debian/rules`?

Comment: Quesetion edited with my further experiments. It still doesn't work, but it is getting better.