# Installing a created .deb package

Tags: debian, php, packaging

Following that question: [Creating a .deb package for PHP 7.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383360/creating-a-deb-package-for-php-7-1)

I have what seems to be a .deb package. [Here](https://pastebin.com/ErVeX4Wb) is a pastebin with the return of `dpkg-deb -c  /var/cache/pbuilder/result/php_7.1.7-1_amd64.deb` (too long to be put here).

But the installation on another VM doesn't work:

```
# dpkg -i php_7.1.7-1_amd64.deb
(Lecture de la base de données... 55608 fichiers et répertoires déjà installés.)
Préparation du dépaquetage de php_7.1.7-1_amd64.deb ...
Dépaquetage de php (7.1.7-1) sur (7.1.7-1) ...
Paramétrage de php (7.1.7-1) ...

# dpkg -L php
/.
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/php
/usr/share/doc/php/README.WIN32-BUILD-SYSTEM
/usr/share/doc/php/README.EXT_SKEL.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.SUBMITTING_PATCH.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.UNIX-BUILD-SYSTEM.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.TESTING.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.NEW-OUTPUT-API.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/copyright
/usr/share/doc/php/README.TESTING2.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.Debian
/usr/share/doc/php/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.STREAMS.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.input_filter.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.md
/usr/share/doc/php/README.SELF-CONTAINED-EXTENSIONS.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.MAILINGLIST_RULES
/usr/share/doc/php/README.RELEASE_PROCESS.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.namespaces.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.PARAMETER_PARSING_API.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.REDIST.BINS.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/README.GIT-RULES.gz
/usr/share/doc/php/NEWS.gz
```

(sorry it's in french)

PHP isn't installed anywhere. Does anyone have another hint which might help me?

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: Thanks. Could you run `ls -l /var/cache/pbuilder/result/php_7.1.7-1_amd64.deb` on the build machine, and `ls -l php_7.1.7-1_amd64.deb` on the target machine?

Comment: If you re-run your command with a suitable locale, say `C`, the command output would be in English. Also, as Stephen already suggested, you'd really be better off using the existing PHP 7.l Debian package. Unless this is some kind of learning experience, that is.